# There is error in flutter when make build

Tags: flutter

I am working on flutter project but when I make build then error is generate. Kindly tell me how to fix this error?[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iagh.jpg)[Error1(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqciQ.jpg)[Error1(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMHZI.jpg)[Error1(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hgPA.jpg)

Comment: Please provide code that throws those errors. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26590083).

Comment: No error in code.I removed all errors.